# How to solve [No available formula with the name "redis".] with homebrew

Tags: redis, homebrew

I can't install Redis server on my MacBook using brew.

```
$ brew install redis
```

It throws this error for me :
No available formula with the name "redis".
What do i do to solve this error ?

Here is a SS of my terminal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u6fp.png

Comment: After trying all i could, i decided to uninstall my homebrew, NB:// this also removed my Node server as i deleted everything about it.

I had to reinstall node, then reinstall homebrew before the redis package successfuly worked.

So apparently, the problem was with my homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Answer (score 0):

The redis package in brew is called redis-server. Try:

`brew install redis-server`

Though, alternatively you might want the latest [redis-stack](https://github.com/redis-stack/homebrew-redis-stack), a redis with all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run `brew doctor` and see if you get any useful output. In my case I got this:

```
Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core
```